# Get all the users who satisfies both language filter

Tags: mysql, laravel

I would like to grab all of the users who speak `Portuguese` and `English`.

Right now I have the following SQL command:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM   `users_language` 
       WHERE  `users`.`id` = 
          `users_language`.`user_id` 
           AND ( `language_id` = 'en'
           OR `language_id` = 'pt' )
```

I'm using `Laravel` as a framework. A user can add several languages to be filteres such as `Portuguese`, `English`, `German`, etc... Which that is why I have the following code:

```
$candidates->whereHas('user.languages', function ($q) use ($request){
                    foreach($request->language as $index => $language_code){
                        $q->where('language_id', $language_code);
//                        $q->where('speaking', '>=', $request->speaking[$index]);
//                        $q->where('writing', '>=', $request->writting[$index]);
//                        $q->where('comprehension', '>=', $request->comprehension[$index]);
                    }
                });
```

The first query is a simplified version for those who do not understand `Laravel/PHP`. The full query for this is written in the following:

```
SELECT `user_id`, 
       `cover_letter`, 
       `selected` 
FROM   `jobs_application` 
WHERE  `jobs_application`.`job_id` = ? 
       AND `jobs_application`.`job_id` IS NOT NULL 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   `users` 
                   WHERE  `jobs_application`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
                          AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                      FROM   `users_language` 
                                      WHERE  `users`.`id` = 
                                             `users_language`.`user_id` 
                                             AND `language_id` = ? 
                                             AND `language_id` = ?))
```

Whenever I select a user who speaks `Portuguese` and `English` I don't get the only user who do speaks both languages. I would like to retrieve the users who speak the language provided by the filters.

I have tried using `whereIn()` but this will not let me filter later by `speaking`, `writing` and `comprehension`. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, I commented in the query so please let me know if it will give you an idea on how to use it.

This selects distinct user ids matching all the users speaking all the languages provided from the filter. You can retrieve more columns in the select clause, but you will also need to use the same columns in the group by clause.

```
select u.user_id from users as u
inner join users_language as ul
on ul.user_id = u.user_id
where ul.language_id in (1, 6, 7, 11) # IDs of the languages, you can continue the WHERE clause here by adding AND appending your different cases.
group by u.user_id
having count(ul.language_id) = 4; # number 4 comes from the total count of languages in the IN clause. I have 4 ids there, hence 4 here.
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution . Any idea how to do it via Laravel Eloquent? I'm trying to do it but I can't use the alias for the tables inside `whereHas()` https://pastebin.com/nqMTwE1J

Using the raw query works like a charm

Comment: Have you tried using the Query Builder of Laravel instead of Eloquent? 
Something like this:

DB::table('users as u')
->select('u.id')
->join('users_language as ul', 'ul.user_id', '=', 'u.user_id')
->whereIn('ul.language_id', [10, 15])
->groupBy('u.user_id')
->havingRaw('count(ul.language_id)', [2])
->get();

Comment: Your solution had worked for me until I get to the point where I had to filter several `where()`s. You can check it here with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458407/check-for-multiple-where-in-several-field